# How to remove border of SWT Button so that it seems like a Label

Tags: java, swt

I have created a button on which Image is Set in SWT. I want to remove border of button. So it looks like a label. Please help anyone.

Below Code Snippet:

```java
breakNodeButton = new Button(this, SWT.TRANSPARENT);
breakNodeButton.setBackground(new Color(getDisplay(), 204, 204, 204));
Image breakNodeLabelImg = ...
breakNodeButton.setImage(breakNodeLabelImg);
```

Comment: You can't just remove the border. You can use a `PaintListener` to draw the button completely in your code.

Comment: Code is added in Question Please check,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Greg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670892/greg-449) suggested, you can use a `PaintListener` to override the appearance of the button.

For example:

```java
Button button = new Button( shell, SWT.PUSH );
button.addPaintListener( new PaintListener() {
  @Override
  public void paintControl( PaintEvent event ) {
    event.gc.setBackground( event.display.getSystemColor( SWT.COLOR_GREEN ) );
    event.gc.fillRectangle( event.x, event.y, event.width, event.height );
    Image image = event.display.getSystemImage( SWT.ICON_QUESTION );
    event.gc.drawImage( image, 0, 0 );
  }
} );
```

The paint code will draw the question mark image in the top-left corner on top of a green background.

Note that the `computeSize()` method of the button still consults the (empty) text and image to compute the preferred size of the button.

As this probably isn't the size you want, you should set the buttons image to the one you are using in the paint code or advise the layout to use a pre-computed size, e.g. by setting suitable `GridData` or `RowData`

Alternatively you can use a `Label` and add a `MouseListener` to emulate the selection listener of a Button. However, a Label, by default, cannot gain keyboard focus through tab traversal and thus might not serve as a full replacement for a `Button`.

Comment: @RahulTripathi  If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an `SWT.FLAT` ToolBar with a single ToolItem:

```
ToolBar toolBar = new ToolBar(parent, SWT.FLAT);
ToolItem item = new ToolItem(toolBar, SWT.PUSH);
item.setText("Button text"); // Remove if you don't need text
item.setImage(display.getSystemImage(SWT.ICON_INFORMATION)); // Remove if you don't need image
```

That's it!

Comment: I like this solution.  It works great for my case where I wanted an SWT.CHECK style button, but did not want to have to implement a fully custom PaintListener to handle the CHECK state rendering. Thanks!